# Verify collection as a method parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How can I verify that `ohterClassMock.MethodToTest()` was called with `contracts`?

That it was called with `contract`, that have `Id = 1` and `Param2 = 34` and also with `contract2`, which has `Id = 2` and `Param2 = 56`.

This is my code:

```
GoodClass goodClass = new GoodClass(ohterClassMock);
...
var contracts = new List<Contract>();
var contract = new Contract{ Id = 1, Param2 = 34 };
contracts.Add(contract);
var contract2 = new Contract { Id = 2, Param2 = 56 };
contracts.Add(contract2);

goodClass.DoSomething(contracts);

ohterClassMock.Verify(mock => mock.MethodToTest(It.IsAny<contracts>()));
```

I know that it can be tested for every item in the collection:

```
ohterClassMock.Verify(mock => mock.MethodToTest(It.Is<Contract>(contract => contract.Id == 1)));
...
```

but maybe there is some other syntax to call it in one line of code?

*Updated:*

```
goodClass.DoSomething(contracts);
```

calls

```
foreach(Contract contract in contracts)
{
   ohterClassMock.MethodToTest(contract);
}
```

Comment: Not very clear. What do you want to test exactly? That the contracts were not modified?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I want to test, that ohterClassMock was called with contracts. And to test that all the items of contracts have the right value.

Comment: So you want to test the Test? The call is right there. You should be wondering about the results of DoSomething().

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I want to test, that if I call goodClass.DoSomething(contracts) -  ohterClassMock.MethodToTest(contract) will be called with all the items from contracts Collection and that all this item have the valid parameters

Comment: You shouldn't test that a function calls another function correctly.  You should test that A) function #1 returns or manipulates the contracts correctly, without knowing anything about *how* it does it, and B) that the second function does the right thing when given a correctly manipulated set of input.

Comment: @Bobson - maybe you are right ) Sometimes I write this kind of tests - verify that A calls B..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly to answer the question at hand, you have local variables for the individual contracts already, so you can just re-use them:

```
ohterClassMock.Verify(mock => mock.MethodToTest(It.Is<Contract>(c => contract.Equals(c))));
ohterClassMock.Verify(mock => mock.MethodToTest(It.Is<Contract>(c => contract2.Equals(c))));
```

This assumes you have implemented `IEquatable<Contract>` and/or overridden `Object.Equals` on your Contract object.

Given the behavior of most test and mocking frameworks, it will probably save you a lot of grief to go ahead and override `Object.ToString` so that failed tests will print out nicer expected/actual values than the fully-qualified type names.

Also, as an aside, you can create your list with a collection initializer if you do so after building your individual contracts:

```
var contracts = new List<Contract> { contract, contract2 };
```

Or, if your method takes in `IEnumerable<Contract>`, it may be even simpler to use:

```
var contracts = new [] { contract, contract2 };
```